# Convert Many-to-Many relationship to single class with ADO.Net

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I have `ViewModel`

**UserGroup.cs**

```
public class UserGroup
{
    public User User { get; set; }

    public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to have the `User` and all related `Groups`. The problem is that the `query` returns duplicates of all users if there is more than 1 group related to him (and It's expected of course). The first thing that comes to my mind is to fetch all the users with single query and then foreach user to get the groups related to him and push it in the list. But I'm looking for a better way (if there is) to do that.

The relationship is made with junction table.

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT u.UserName, ug.GroupName FROM auth.UserUserGroup uug 
INNER JOIN [auth].[User] u ON u.UserId = uug.UserId 
INNER JOIN auth.UserGroup ug ON ug.UserGroupId = uug.UserGroupId
```

Comment: to get the user-related details, read only the first row of the result and populate the User object. This is ok because the user details are the same each time anyway. Then to get the group details, read each row in turn and populate the group list. Ok so it's not the most elegant idea but it means only one query is required.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure someone will have a more elegant solution, but I've used Linq to construct a tiered object a number of times

```
var dbRecords = repository.Get(userId); // However you are getting your records, do that here
var result = dbRecords.GroupBy(x => x.UserId)
    .Select(g => new UserGroup
    {
        User = new User { UserName = g.First().UserName },
        Groups = g.Select(y => new Group { GroupName = y.GroupName }
    }
);
```

I've tried to use your object names. Hopefully I didn't make any mistakes